# My code keep saying AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'formart'

Tags: python

```
salary = float(input("What is your salary?"))
  if salary > 1250.00 :
     new = salary*0.1
    print("the increase was {}".formart(new))
if salary <= 1250.00:
    new = salary*0.15
    print("the increase was {}".formart(new))
```

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 7, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'formart'
```

Comment: You have typo in your code. It should be "format", not "formart".

Comment: And bad indentation, too.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple typo, `formart` should be `format`, also bad indentation:

```
salary = float(input("What is your salary?"))
if salary > 1250.00 :
    new = salary*0.1
    print("the increase was {}".format(new))
if salary <= 1250.00:
    new = salary*0.15
    print("the increase was {}".format(new))
```

Also you can use `'%'`:

```
salary = float(input("What is your salary?"))
if salary > 1250.00 :
    new = salary*0.1
    print("the increase was %s"%(new))
if salary <= 1250.00:
    new = salary*0.15
    print("the increase was %s"%(new))
```

Or f-strings if version > pytho 3.6:

```
salary = float(input("What is your salary?"))
if salary > 1250.00 :
    new = salary*0.1
    print(f"the increase was {new}")
if salary <= 1250.00:
    new = salary*0.15
    print(f"the increase was {new}")
```

Or best in this case:

```
salary = float(input("What is your salary?"))
if salary > 1250.00 :
    new = salary*0.1
    print("the increase was", new)
if salary <= 1250.00:
    new = salary*0.15
    print("the increase was", new)
```